# Is creating a custom PrincipalPermission attribute a good idea?

Tags: wcf, cas

I need to check for both Roles and a concept called Privilieges, which is distinct from roles in a WCF service.

As PrincipalPermission is sealed, I was thinking about creating a custom attribute for the same.

Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

The Role concept for permissions is fairly simplistic and does not allow sufficient granularity for many applications.  If you create your own IPermission implementation it works very nicely. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607467/wcf-web-service-authorization-iprincipal-etc-how-do-i-use-my-own-permissions) provides a little more detail.